# Managing and motivating a collaborator

Tags: colleagues

I have a collaborator who is working with me on a project. I guess he is too slow not because he is not capable but rather afraid of doing mistakes (on the problem we are working on) and perhaps he procrastinates a lot. Because of this, the project is suffering immeasurably. We have passed all the pre-decided deadlines. How can I manage and motivate him without hurting him the least?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/12382/8077

Comment: Hi Ramanuja. Tough situation as it seems, but unfortunately, it's really too broad. IPS expects Q/A to set a single goal to achieve, and a skill to learn/improve. *Managing and motivating* has books about it, and it's not really for all persons, as not all cases are covered and every individual is different. Please narrow down your Q (edit), thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can sympathize with your collaborator, I sometimes have trouble working on stuff and it's often due to fear of mistakes / failure / looking dumb / being overwhelmed.  One thing that helps me, might help your collaborator, is to help him break the project down into smaller, achievable tasks.  If he's feeling overwhelmed that will help, because now he can just focus on something that he can finish.